# Should I use Azure Service (such as Scheduler) for sending rest messages to my bot, or use a separate thread for notifications?

Tags: azure, office365, microsoft-graph-api, botframework

I am creating a bot using Microsoft Bot Framework (BotBuilder) and want it to message the user when an appointment is about to begin.
I currently use Microsoft Graph api to access the user's Office 365 calendar and store the appointments. A background thread then keeps track of time and then messages the user when an appointment is about to start.
The current idea is to use Graph webhooks to notify my bot about new appointments.

My question is, would it be smarter to use an Azure service (such as Scheduler) to keep track of the appointments, and send rest messages to my bot, which will then send a message to the user?
My worry is, that as the amount of users rise, the amount of appointments and time checks will become too large, and that maybe Azure services would be able to handle it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a perfect fit for **Azure Functions** with a HTTP Trigger.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook

> This article explains how to configure and work with HTTP triggers and bindings in Azure Functions. With these, you can use Azure Functions to build serverless APIs and respond to webhooks.
>
> Azure Functions provides the following bindings:
>
> - An HTTP trigger lets you invoke a function with an HTTP request. This can be customized to respond to webhooks.
> - An HTTP output binding allows you to respond to the request.

Comment: Thanks. Azure Functions look promising. I was suggested that I use Azure Functions with a timer trigger to list all appointments scheduled for today (each day), then for each of those start an Azure Scheduler job, which would then post the notification to my bot, which then messaged the user about the upcoming appointment.

I am convinced it would scale better, but it would seem easier if the Graph api had a webhook for when appointments start/end/are about to begin. I haven't found such a webhook though, only for creation/deletion/update of appointments.

Comment: The timer trigger is fine, however there's no need to involve Azure Scheduler at all, just post to your bot from within the Function app.